# No recipients defined from server Nodemailer . From local work fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I need help with my code, when i use my app in local, everything works perfect. But when i run in server, the app show me this error. Try sending me a message from the form in this link https://silvioli-cv.herokuapp.com/contacto
I don't know what is wrong.

**This is my app.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config();

var express = require('express'),
 app = express(),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
 flash = require('connect-flash');

// APP CONFIG
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

// FLASH
app.use(
 require('express-session')({
  secret: 'Nana es la perra mas bella del mundo',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
 })
);
app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.locals.message = req.flash('success');
 next();
});

// RUTAS
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('perfil');
});

app.get('/contacto', function(req, res) {
 res.render('contacto');
});

// NODEMAILER CONFIG
app.post('/contacto', function(req, res) {
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
   type: 'OAuth2',
   user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
   clientId: process.env.GMAIL_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
   clientSecret: process.env.GMAIL_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
   refreshToken: process.env.GMAIL_OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
   accessToken: process.env.GMAIL_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,
   expires: Number.parseInt(process.env.GMAIL_OAUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRE, 10)
  }
 });
 var mailOptions = {
  from: req.body.nombre + '<' + req.body.email + '>',
  to: process.env.EMAIL_RECIEVER,
  subject: req.body.asunto,
  html: `
   <div>
    <p>${req.body.nombre}</p>
    <p>${req.body.email}</p>
    <p>${req.body.asunto}</p>
    <p>${req.body.mensaje}</p>

   </div>
   `
 };
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   res.send(500, err.message);
  } else {
   console.log('Email sent');
   req.flash('success', 'Su mensaje ha sido enviado con éxito. Muchas gracias.');
   res.redirect('/contacto');
  }
 });
});

// SERVIDOR
// app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
//  console.log('Conectado');
// });
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

**And this is my form contact**

```html
<%- include("partials/header") %>


<header class="card-header">
    <h2>Contacto</h2>
</header>

<% if(message && message.length > 0){ %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-success col-md-8" role="alert">
        <%= message %>
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>

        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Envíame un correo</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form action="/contacto" method="POST" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre (requerido)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email (requerido)</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" name="asunto">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="mensaje">Su mensaje</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="4"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Enviar mensaje</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

Comment: what is the error shown?

Comment: When i submit form contact says “no recipients defined “

Comment: I can’t upload an image because this is my first post here

Comment: You don't need to upload images. Text is good enough, and preferred.